# which rails vs rails -v vs which ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am still new to Ruby/Rails, about a month now, and I want to make sure I understand these seemingly important concepts. Especially since I anticipate having to work with multiple versions.

**which ruby** - returns a path.  Is this the current or default Ruby interpreter?  If I execute an .rb file, is that path the version of Ruby being used?

**ruby -v** - seems to be the ruby version being currently used (directly corresponding with `rvm use ruby-#.#.#`)

**rails -v** - Which Rails is it giving me if I have multiple? Doesn't seem to be the latest version.

**which rails** - Seems to correspond at least in part with the Rails version you get from rails -v, in that when I use rvm use ruby-#.#.# and change between ruby versions, the output from `which rails/rails -v` changes.

Can you set which rails version gets invoked when you do things like rake db:seed, or is it always going to use the same Rails version as the app that you get when you do `rake/rails about`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which` is a Unix utility that searches your PATH to find an executable that matches the argument you've supplied and returns the full path to that executable. You can do this with any executable included in your path, not just Ruby or Rails.

When you type `ruby -v`, on the other hand, you're actually invoking the Ruby executable with `-v` as a command line argument, telling it to return its version. You're always going to get the version of your current Ruby. Same applies to Rails.

Switching versions of Ruby and Rails depends on which management tool you're using. For [RVM](https://rvm.io/) (Ruby Version Manager), `use ruby 2.5.0` switches the current version of Ruby to Ruby 2.5.0 (assuming you've previously installed it). For [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), you generally want to edit your project's `.ruby_version` file, or you can use `rbenv shell 2.5.0` to switch to Ruby 2.5.0 on the fly. [Uncle Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+management+tools&oq=ruby+management+tools) has more information on more obscure management tools.

Comment: I also thought a bit about the last part of my question, and realize I had a bit of a brain fart.  You'd only care about which Rails version when you're creating a new app with `rails _5.1.4_ new appname`.  And you'd never do actions like `rake` except within the context of a specific app.